# Django forms.FloatField and IntegerField accepting text input without validation error

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that asks for a FloatField, and IntegerField.

```
conc = forms.FloatField(label='Concentration (uM)',required=False)
muxlevel = forms.IntegerField(label='Multiplex level ',required=False)
```

If a user enters say 0.5, into the muxlevel field, form.is_valid() returns False, and the form is returned saying

"Enter a whole number."

Which is what I expect (it's awesome actually).  But if user enters text into either field, say 'asdf', the validation doesn't complain, form.is_valid() returns True, and the value of the form.cleaned_data['muxlevel'] is None. The same thing happens for entering text into the FloatField conc.

That's not what I would have expected, I would rather the user get returned to the form saying "Enter a whole number" or "Enter a floating point value".

I've searched and don't see this problem reported. In fact the documentation says that...

- Normalizes to: A Python float
- Validates that the given value is a float
- Leading and trailing whitespace is allowed, as in Python’s float() function.

EDIT - The view looks like

```
from .forms import *
def scr_query(request):
    summ = ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QueryForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            if (form.cleaned_data['conc']):         
                summ += "Concentration < " + str(form.cleaned_data['conc_upper']) + "<br>"
            if (form.cleaned_data['muxlevel']):

                summ += "Muxlevel > " + str(form.cleaned_data['muxlevel']) + "<br>"
```

and the form looks like this

```
class QueryForm(forms.Form):

    conc = forms.FloatField(label='Concentration (uM)',required=False)
    muxlevel = forms.IntegerField(label='Multiplex level ',required=False)
```

My reading tells me that python's float() actually gets called to check if the provided string can be coerced into a float.  If I do that at the console using float('abc') I get the expected exception.  So not sure why It's getting converted to None. Is there some form of text stripping happening before the call to float(), so that it's getting a blank value, and float('') is returning None, as expected?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Can you show your view?

Comment: @Alisdair,  Django 1.8.9, post edited to show the view.  Everything else works, it's just the validation that doesn't behave as expected. Thanks.

Comment: The indentation that you've posted doesn't look right. Can you show the full `QueryForm`? Try printing/logging `request.POST` to check that the values are present.

Comment: Code Fragment.  Indents are fixed.  The point is that the view prints out values when they're properly entered, trips a validation error when a non-integer number is entered for the IntegerField, but does not show a validation error if a string is entered into either of the form fields, instead returning a valid form, with a value of None for the variable.

Comment: If I do `form = QueryForm({'conc': 'a string', 'muxlevel': 'another string'}); print(form.errors)` I get the following errors `<ul class="errorlist"><li>muxlevel<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a whole number.</li></ul></li><li>conc<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a number.</li></ul></li></ul>`. Therefore I think that either there's something weird in your form that you haven't shown, or `request.POST` isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort on debugging that.  I didn't know to debug it that way.  Nice.  Let me look more closely now with that information.

Answer (score 2):

As @Alasdair has mentioned the problem is with the `request.POST`. It contains no data for field. But the reason for this is the widget. By default Django uses `forms.NumberInput` (depending on your localization settings ofc) and it prevents non-numerical data to be sent in request. So, if you change to `muxlevel = forms.IntegerField(label='Multiplex level ',required=False, widget=forms.TextInput())` you will see correct error message.